# Write out results of for-loop of distance measures in matrix form in R

Tags: r, for-loop, distance, string-matching, stringdist

Suppose I have something like the following vector:

```
text <- as.character(c("string1", "str2ing", "3string", "stringFOUR", "5tring", "string6", "s7ring", "string8", "string9", "string10"))
```

I want to execute a loop that does pair-wise comparisons of the edit distance of all possible combinations of these strings (ex: string 1 to string 2, string 1 to string 3, and so forth). The output should be in a matrix form with rows equal to number of strings and columns equal to number of strings.

I have the following code below:

```
#Matrix of pair-wise combinations
m <- expand.grid(text,text)

#Define number of strings
n <- c(1:10)

#Begin loop; "method='osa'" in stringdist is default
for (i in 1:10) {
  n[i] <- stringdist(m[i,1], m[i,2], method="osa")
  write.csv(data.frame(distance=n[i]),file="/File/Path/output.csv",append=TRUE)
  print(n[i])
  flush.console()
}
```

**The stringdist() function is from the stringdist{} package but the function is also bundled in the base utils package as adist()**

*My question is, why is my loop not writing the results as a matrix, and how do I stop the loop from overwriting each individual distance calculation (ie: save all results in matrix form)?*

Comment: +1 for a nice, clean reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using `stringdistmatrix` instead of `stringdist`
(especially if you are using `expand.grid`)

```
 res <- stringdistmatrix(text, text)
 dimnames(res) <- list(text, text)  
 write.csv(res, "file.csv")
```

---

As for your concrete question:  *"My question is, why is my loop not writing the results as a matrix"*
It is not clear why you would expect the output to be a matrix?  You are calculating an element at a time, saving it to a vector and then writing that vector to disk.

Also, you should be aware that the arugments of `write.csv` are mostly useless (they are there, I believe, just to remind the user of what the defaults are).  Use `write.table` instead

If you want to do this iteratively, I would do the following:

```
# Column names, outputted only one time
write.table(rbind(names(data.frame(i=1, distance=n[1])))
            ,file="~/Desktop/output.csv",append=FALSE   # <~~ Don't append for first run.
             , sep=",", col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)

for (i in 1:10) {
  n[[i]] <- stringdist(m[i,1], m[i,2], method="osa")
  write.table(data.frame(i=i, distance=n[i]),file="~/Desktop/output.csv"
              ,append=TRUE, sep=",", col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)
  print(n[[i]])
  flush.console()
}
```

Comment: R Sessions abort with large strings (due to RAM/memory issues). Hence why I am using the matrix notation, stringdist() as opposed to stringdistmatrix(), and periodically saving & printing results throughout the loop execution

Comment: @DVHughes that makes sense. Try using `write.table` instead  (see edit)